# Сортировка списка словарей по двум ключам словаря

Tags: python

Необходимо отсортировать список словарей который приходит ответом от апи.
Cписок выглядит подобным способом. Отсортировать нужно по полю date и time т.е f'{[date]} {[time]}'

```
 ['callConfirmationStatus': None,
  'clientComment': None,
  'clientId': 31072,
  'clinicId': 1,
  'coMagic': None,
  'createdAt': 1635407965,
  'date': '2021-11-20',
  'duration': 15,
  'entryTypeIds': [2686],
  'id': 47251,
  'note': '{{ID СДЕЛКИ: 21360756}}  ',
  'orderId': 39820,
  'roistat': None,
  'status': 'paid',
  'time': '13:00',
  'updatedAt': 1637399813,
  'userId': 59},
  {'callConfirmationStatus': None,
  'clientComment': None,
  'clientId': 29173,
  'clinicId': 1,
  'coMagic': None,
  'createdAt': 1633504927,
  'date': '2021-11-20',
  'duration': 20,
  'entryTypeIds': [2856],
  'id': 44169,
  'note': '{{ID СДЕЛКИ: 21098836}} ',
  'orderId': 39780,
  'roistat': None,
  'status': 'paid',
  'time': '11:00',
  'updatedAt': 1637394246,
  'userId': 89},
]
```

есть пример такой сортировки на php, но как это реализовать на python?

```
function date_sort($a, $b) 
{
    if (strtotime($a['attributes']['date'].' '.$a['attributes']['time']) == strtotime($b['attributes']['date'].' '.$b['attributes']['time'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a['attributes']['date'].' '.$a['attributes']['time']) < strtotime($b['attributes']['date'].' '.$b['attributes']['time'])) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($list, "date_sort");
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка списка словарей по подстроке в значениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194488/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо указать функции сортировки данные по каким необходимо сортировать.

```
#data = [{...}, {...}]
result = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (item["date"], item["time"]))
```

Или прямо в исходном списке *(инлайн)*, если нет необходимости его сохранять.

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: (item["date"], item["time"]))
```